# Login via ssh does not source the .cshrc file in my home directory (MobaXTerm Professional)

Tags: ssh, tcsh, csh, mobaxterm

During my login to my Linux environment via ssh the .cshrc file in my home directory is not read. Each time I had to read this file after login via source ~/.cshrc

I use MobaXTerm Professional 10.5 as a tool and my shell is a tcsh shell which I can confirm via

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/tcsh
```

I already tried to add files like **.login** and **.tcshrc** to source the **.cshrc** file, but nothing helped.

How can I enable reading the **.cshrc** file via ssh login?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple files parsed by this shell:

```
/etc/csh.cshrc
/etc/csh.login
~/.tcshrc
~/.cshrc
~/.login
```

The two firsts are system wide.
The tree others are user related.

Maybe there is something wrong in your syntaxe. 
Try a simple file `~/.tcshrc` containing:

```
echo "test"
```

It should output "test" before the prompt like this:

```
workstation:~ user$ cat ~/.tcshrc 
echo "test"
workstation:~ user$ /bin/tcsh 
test
[workstation:~] user%
```

Same output on remote with the following command:
`ssh -t user@workstation tcsh`

Comment: And of the three user related files, `.tcshrc` is only read if it exists, and `.cshrc` is only read if it exists and `.tcshrc` **does not**.   `.login` is only read on login shells.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure csh is actually running!

Run `which csh` to get location of csh.

Run `ls -l /path/returned/by/which/csh`

In my case, somehow `csh` was mapped to `tcsh`.